# Comparar un elemento de array con el contenido de un input

Tags: javascript, html, formularios

suplico su ayuda con el siguiente problema:
Tengo un quizz de imagenes, cada imagen tiene su input y hay un botón general para revisar si el contenido del input es correcto a la imagen.
Hasta el momento tengo el siguiente código....

```
const inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('datoInput');
const inputsArray = [...inputs]; //Convertir nodelist a array
//Le añadí un id a cada input para acceder al contenido
inputsArray.forEach((input,i)=>{
input.id='input'+i;
});
```

Ahora debo comparar el contenido de dos arreglos, el creado por el usuario y el declarado en el código...

```
const arreglo1 = ['UNO', 'DOS', 'TRES'];
//el arreglo 2 sería el inputsArray
```

Estoy detenido en esta parte debido a que no encuentro la solución adecuada para saber si el primer elemento de cada arreglo son idénticos. Mi último intento fue el siguiente:

```
const checkInput = () =>{
  for (let i = 0; i < arreglo1.length; i++) {

    let elemento1 = arreglo1[i];
    let elemento2 = document.getElementById('input'+i).value;
    
    if (elemento1 == elemento2.toUpperCase()) {
        alert('son iguales')
    }else{
        alert('No son iguales')
    }
  }
}
```

No tuve éxito con está función debido a que me comprueba todos los campos y no logro hacer que solo me compruebe un input y un elemento.
De ante mano gracias por leerme, espero mi redacción sea lo más clara posible para recibir algún apoyo a mi problema.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres evitar el **alert()** en los *input* vacios tan solo debes poner un condicional que lo compruebe de este modo:

```
if(elemento2 !== "") {
```

El **for** igualmente recorrerá todos los *input*, pero el *alert()* sólo se mostrará en los casos con valores.

Snippet de ejemplo:

```js
const arreglo1 = ['UNO', 'DOS', 'TRES'];
const checkInput = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < arreglo1.length; i++) {
    let elemento1 = arreglo1[i];


    if (document.getElementById(''input' + i')) {
      let elemento2 = document.getElementById('input' + i).value;   
      if(elemento2 !== "") {
        if (elemento1 == elemento2.toUpperCase()) {
          alert('son iguales')
        } else {
          alert('No son iguales')
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
checkInput()
```

```html
<input id="input0" value="UNO">
<input id="input1" value="">
<input id="input2" value="TRESCIENTOS">
```

### Actualización

Para evitar el hipotético caso de que no exista un `input+i` en la secuencia del **for** acabo de agregar este otro condicional:

```
if (document.getElementById(''input' + i')) {
```

donde se verifica su existencia antes de proceder a la comparación de los datos del array.  Eso provoca el salto de dicho elemento del array, el cual no se verifica pues no tiene su correspondiente `input+i`, pero al menos ya no da error y puede continuar con el resto.

Comment: En realidad me tendría que comprobar los inputs con contenido, hice énfasis en un solo elemento debido a que me comprobaba todo el array... hay alguna solución a ello?

Comment: @richardsanchez acabo de modificar mi respuesta, dime si es eso lo que pretendias o si sigo sin entenderte bien

Comment: Pienso que si es lo que soluciona mi problema, lamentablemente me arroja que el elemento 2 tiene un valor null y no trae el contenido del input.

Comment: pero eso te debe ocurrir en otra parte del código que no vemos en la pregunta, no?   es decir, es un efecto colateral de dejarlo vacio aqui:  `<input id="input1" value="">` ... es decir, te hubiera ocurrido igualmente sin aplicar esta respuesta (¿o se me escapa algo?)

Comment: Solo puedo detectar que el error proviene de poner .value dentro del for y en la consola me arroja el siguiente mensaje: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')
    at HTMLButtonElement.checkInput

Comment: Pues diria que no lo estas usando igual que en ejemplo, y me refiero a los mismos inputs que hay aqui, porque ni en este snippet ni en este otro jsfiddle da ese error: https://jsfiddle.net/c9sL27zq/,  o bien tu implementación con tu **for** abarca un rango superior de ids que los que realmente existen o bien tus inputs no son seguidos y se saltan alguno, es decir, por ejemplo, tienes input1, input3, pero no input2 aunque este vacio...

Comment: Acabo de actualizar mi respuesta con una breve explicación, a ver si así solucionas el problema, pero cada vez le veo menos sentido a que eso ocurra, pues parece otro error en alguna otra parte.